# How does "dancing" work?

Tags: runner2

How many points does one get when you "dance"?  How many seconds does this last? I'd like to know so I can cram as many of these into open parts so I can get more points.

Do points received from dancing also play into difficulty level? Does playing on Just Right give less points than playing on Hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dancing is first unlocked at Level 2-1.  You simply press the button "A" on a keyboard, and it performs a dance move.

The key issue of a dance move is that when "dancing", you cannot do any other action (sliding, jumping, blocking, and kicking), so be careful when dancing; with great dancing comes great responsibility.

Dancing nets you different points based on what score multiplier you have. The following levels show what points you receive for each time you "dance" at which multiplier.

- Hyper - 2000 points
- Mega - 4000 points
- Super - 6000 points
- Ultra - 8000 points
- Extra - 10000 points

Dancing does pay off though.  This is from 1-1 (The very first level) on the Just Right mode.  Look at the score comparison between me, @badp, and a buddy of mines:

[image]

As you can see, even without the Bonus Challenge (50k points, for skipping checkpoint) the difference between badp's score and mines is substantially a lot more.