# What are the main differences between Bit.Trip Runner and Bit.Trip Runner 2?

Tags: runner2, bit-trip-runner

What are the differences? Besides the graphics changing, what are the main features of Runner 2 that separate it from Bit.Trip Runner?

I've played Bit Trip Runner quite a bit, and I don't want to come into Runner2 with misconceptions about what gameplay will be like, or how different functions have changed and whatnot.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: I don't understand why this receiving massive downvotes.

Comment: It's not like I have the ability to just look through the game code and see what is placed where.  Is this question useful? Certainly is.

Comment: I see no usefulness to this question; they're two separate games.  The sequel will be bigger and better.

Comment: @fbueckert That's hardly a valid generalization.  Consider: "What is the difference between Super Smash Bros Melee and Brawl?".  A: "What a useless question, the sequel is bigger and better."  That's not a useful response, to either that question or this one.

Comment: @jw013 You're talking about an ever-changing metagame, because those games are played competitively.  It's still a *bad* question, because you're comparing two different products.  What good does it do you to know what game A can do better or differently than game B?  There's a reason we have a version-differences tag; to compare the same game against itself in another form.  *That's* an objective and useful question.  This?  Not so much.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree with your argument in the case of game A and game B, but this is not that case.  This is a case of game A and game A+1.  Someone who is familiar with game A is going to bring some preconceptions into game A+1 that someone new to both will likely not have.  If game A+1 has changed / violated those preconceptions, you are saying it is useless for a game A player to ask about those?  I still disagree.  "Game A+1 is so different it's an entirely different game; there's no benefit in comparing it to game A" *is* a valid answer in *specific cases*.

Comment: @jw013 You're welcome to your disagreement.  I feel this question is not useful, ergo have downvoted it.  You feel it's useful, and have probably upvoted it.  That's fine.  The system works.

Comment: The Asker has made no mention about *why* he cares about the differences. If he clarified *why* he was interested in the differences, it would be a better question. (And less deserving of downvotes)

Comment: @jw013 At the moment this question is an interesting one and I like it, but it lacks detail and feels too broad. I've upvoted on the basis someone managed to answer it in a way that's specific... but I can maybe see why it was downvote... personal opinion here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many things that were added, and a few things were tweaked.

#### Added

- Jump-Slides
- Optional Checkpoints (no more starting from the beginning after dying to the last garbage pile on 3-9!)
- [Loops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106926/how-do-i-maximize-points-from-loops)
- Rails (and their related moves)
- [An option to replay a completed level immediately](https://twitter.com/BitTrip/status/128919970544492544?iid=am-114225476113195718909992280&nid=4%20status_timestamp&uid=86849771), rather than having to exit to the world map.
- [Dancing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106920/how-does-dancing-work)
- Extremely (Obnoxiously?) Eloquent Narration by [Charles Martinet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Martinet)
- Forking Paths
- Built-in Achievement System (aka. Rewards)
- Additional Characters and Alternate Costumes (no longer simply seasonal)

#### Tweaked

- Bonus levels (now a bullseye, instead of the guaranteed retro level)
- Retro Bonus Level (now much more akin to Super Meat Boy's warp zones)
- World Map (no longer strictly linear)
- Springboards. Now trigger when you *hold* up, rather than having to press up while over them. (Thank goodness!)
- Perfect!! mechanic. (now a !+!+!+ mechanic)

#### Stayed the Same

- Basic game mechanics (dodge obstacles, collect shiny!) inc. gliding
- Boss "fights"!

Comment: Once you get to world 3, they have boost pads (boost speed to insane speeds temporarily), instant jump pads (the ones that make a sound effect when you hold up, but you just jump on them and it launches you higher.  Air lifts.